# Trouble Figuring out why my Variable is not updating

Tags: javascript, html

I apologize in advance as what I tried to keep as somewhat clean code has turned into a monstrosity with me trying to figure out why this isn't working. I am trying to increment `turnCount` so I can switch between `player1` and `player2`. I declared it in `ticGame` using var so its more global, then I pass the value to `takeTurn` and it should be incremented there no?

```
    // intializes and starts game

const ticGame = new TicGame();
ticGame.start();
function TicGame(){ 
    // creates and tracks the players
    const board = new Board();
    const player1 = new Player1(board);
    const player2 = new Player2(board);
    this.positions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".column"));
    this.values=[];
    var turnCount=0;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.positions.length; i++){
        this.values[i]=this.positions[i].innerHTML;
    }
    this.start = function() {
        const config = { childList: true };
        const observer = new MutationObserver(() => takeTurn(turnCount));
        board.positions.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el, config));
        takeTurn(turnCount);
    }
    function takeTurn(turnCount) {
    if (turnCount % 2 === 0) 
    {
      console.log(5);
      turnCount++;
      console.log(turnCount);
      player1.takeTurn();

    } 
    else
    {
        console.log(6);
      player2.takeTurn();
      turnCount++;
      console.log(turnCount);
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < ticGame.positions.length; i++){
        ticGame.values[i]=ticGame.positions[i].innerHTML;
    }
 }

    //
    // let a = document.getElementById('box1').innerHTML;
    // console.log(a);
    console.log(this.positions);
    console.log(this.values);
    const winningCombinations = [
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6],
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8]
    ];
    console.log(winningCombinations);
}
// had to pop it out from ticGame because apparently i cant keep it in one object :(
function Board() {
  this.positions = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.column'));
 }
function Player1(board){    
    console.log(1);
    this.takeTurn=function(){
    board.positions.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handleTurnTaken));
    }
}
function Player2(board){
    console.log(2);
    this.takeTurn=function(){
    board.positions.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', handleTurnTakenO));
    }

}
 function handleTurnTaken(event) {
     console.log(3);
    if(event.target.innerText === 'X' || event.target.innerText === 'O'){
        console.log("NAH");
        board.positions.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', handleTurnTaken));
    }
    else{
    event.target.innerText = 'X';
    board.positions.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', handleTurnTaken,true));
    board.positions.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', handleTurnTaken,false));
    }
 }
 // **** me i suck at this 
 function handleTurnTakenO(event) {
     console.log(4);
    if(event.target.innerText === 'X' || event.target.innerText === 'O'){
        console.log("NAH");
        board.positions.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', handleTurnTakenO));
    }
    else{
    event.target.innerText = 'O';
    board.positions.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', handleTurnTakenO,true));
    board.positions.forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', handleTurnTakenO,false));
    }
 }
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
    function takeTurn(turnCount) {
//...
      turnCount++;
```

you're not mutating the global variable `turnCount`, you're mutating the value of variable `turnCount` in the function's scope.

A quick fix will be to get rid of that parameter and go with global variable all the way:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => takeTurn());
// ...
    function takeTurn() {
//...
      turnCount++;
```

A *good* fix would be to rethink the architecture, because it's a little messy.

Comment: I agree with the good fix, but i'm a bit pressed for time. I tried going with a global variable by setting it outside all functions, inside ticGame, inside takeTurn and inside  ticGame.start but it seems to always stay the same value. Where exactly are you recommended i declare it or implement it

Comment: Keep it declared inside where it is, `function TicGame()`, but not redeclare a variable of the same name inside `takeTurn`, including having a function parameter named `turnCount`. It will shadow the declaration from the outside scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "," and ";"
Especially when writing "turnCount++"

Comment: Apologies as i've been switching it in and out of different places, even with ; and ; in place it still does not increment